# A priori $C^0$ estimates for a semi-linear vector Poisson equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, geometric-analysis

### Main Question

Consider a $C^2,H^2$ map $F:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{C}^n$ which satisfies the following equation:
$$
-\Delta F(x) + \sum_i a_i(x)\nabla_iF(x) + B(x)F(x) + |F(x)|^2F(x) = 0
$$
Here $a_i:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ and $B:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ are $C^2$, bounded functions. Furthermore, $B$ is valued in Hermitian matrices. Also define:
$$
\Lambda(B) = \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m, v \in \mathbb{C}^n, |v| = 1} \langle v,B(x)v\rangle
$$
Then the following is true (proofs are below).

**Proposition:** $|F|^2 \le \min(-\Lambda(B),0)$.

My question is about the following slightly modified equation:
$$
-\Delta F(x) + \sum_i A_i(x)\nabla_iF(x) + B(x)F(x) + |F(x)|^2F(x) = 0
$$
Here the $A_i:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ are $C^2$, bounded functions **valued in Hermitian matrices**. I have 4 main questions, and I would appreciate partial answers to any of them.

1. Are there known examples of equations like this where a $C^0$ estimate explicitly **does not** hold?
2. Are there known conditions on the matrix $A_i$ that make a $C^0$ estimate hold?
3. Is there any literature on this problem? I'm having trouble finding anything very helpful on my own.
4. Does anyone have approaches to recommend?

### A Little Context

I'm trying to prove compactness of the space of solutions of a related system of PDE, where the PDE is formulated for sections of some vector bundle with a Riemannian connection. I'm using the above Euclidean space formulation to avoid being too theory heavy.

### Proofs

Here are two proofs of the proposition. They are essentially the same, but the second one reveals a maximum principle going on in the background that's sort of interesting.

**Proof 1:** Let $x_0$ be a point where $|F|^2$ takes its maximum. Then since:
$$-\Delta |F|^2 + 2|\nabla F|^2 = -2\text{Re}\langle F,\Delta F\rangle$$
and $-\Delta |F|^2 \ge 0$ at $x_0$, we have $-\text{Re}\langle F,\Delta F\rangle \ge 0$ at $x_0$. Also, $\nabla_i |F|^2 = \text{Re}\langle F,\nabla_i F\rangle = 0$ for all $i$ at $x_0$.

Now by taking the inner product of the above equation with $F$ and taking the real part we have:
$$
\Lambda(B)|F(x_0)|^2 + |F(x_0)|^4 \le$$
$$ -\text{Re}\langle F,\Delta F\rangle + \sum_i a_i(x_0)\text{Re}\langle F(x_0),\nabla_i F(x_0)\rangle + \langle F(x_0),B(x_0)F(x_0)\rangle + |F(x_0)|^4 = 0
$$
Suppose that $|F(x_0)| \neq 0$. Then we have $\Lambda(B) + |F(x_0)|^2 \le 0$ and our result follows.

**Proof 2:** The idea of this proof is to apply the maximum principle for elliptic systems (see [[Wang90](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-109-02/S0002-9939-1990-1019284-8/S0002-9939-1990-1019284-8.pdf)]).

Write the equation in question as:
$$\Delta F(x) + \sum_i a_i(x)\nabla_iF(x) + \Psi(x,F(x)) = 0$$
with $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ defined by $v \mapsto -B(x)v - v|v|^2$. Now suppose that the proposition were false, i.e suppose that there existed an $F$ such that:
$$
\max(|F|^2) > \min(-\Lambda(B),0)
$$
Let $K$ be the ball of radius $\max(|F|^2)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and for any $v \in \partial K$ let $\nu_K(v) = \frac{-v}{|v|}$ denote the (radial) inward normal vector. Then observe that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $v \in \partial K$ we have:
$$
\langle \nu_K(v),\Psi(x,v)\rangle = -\frac{1}{|v|}\langle v,\Psi(x,v)\rangle \ge \frac{1}{|v|}(\Lambda(B)|v|^2 + |v|^4) = \max(|F|)(\Lambda(B) + \max(|F|^2)) > 0
$$

The maximum principle of [[Wang90](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-109-02/S0002-9939-1990-1019284-8/S0002-9939-1990-1019284-8.pdf)] then implies that since $F(x) \in \partial K$ for some $x$, $F(y) \in \partial K$ for all $y$, i.e $|F(x)|^2$ is constant and $|F(x)|^2 > \min(-\Lambda(B),0)$ everywhere. However, observe that:
$$
\int \Lambda(B)|F(x)|^2 + |F(x)|^4 \le \int |\nabla F|^2 + \langle F,BF\rangle^2 + |F|^4 = $$
$$\int \langle F,-\Delta F + BF + F|F|^2\rangle =  \int \text{Re}\langle F,-\Delta F + \sum_i a_i\nabla_iF + BF + F|F|^2\rangle = 0
$$
Here we use integration by parts from the 2nd to 3rd line. Then we use the facts that $\text{Re}\langle F,\nabla_iF\rangle = 0$ and that the 2nd line is real to go from the 3rd to 4th. This implies that $|F(x)|^2 > \min(-\Lambda(B),0)$ is impossible.